# Symfony2 filling all fields of table related to a Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entities

I have a Entity of TeamMembers. And the TeamMember can have a Specification with a value.

So I have three Entities: TeamMember, Specifications, SpecificationValues.

In the SpecificationValue table I want to store the TeamMember_id, the Specification_id and the value that is just for that TeamMember.

The Specifications and TeamMembers Entities are working. But now I want to show all the Specifications, if I go to the edit route (see code example) of a TeamMember, and have to possibility over there to fill in some values that I want to store in the SpecificationValue Entity.

[TeamMember > Specifications]: list of all specifications, with a extra input field where I can insert some values, that will be stored in the SpecificationValues entity.

```
 <?php

namespace My\BundleName\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * SpecificationValue
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SpecificationValue
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Specifications")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="specification_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $specification;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TeamMembers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teammember_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $teammember;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=222)
     */
    protected $value;

}


/**
 * Specifications
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity 
 */
class Specifications
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SpecificationCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

}

/**
 * TeamMembers
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity 
 */
class TeamMembers
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=250)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $active = true;

}
```

And the Forms are generated with generate:crud.
this is how the form should look like > https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkkdy.png

But is that even possible with Entities in Symfony?

Comment: please clean up your question and provide your entity , repository and formtypes :) please remove unneeded parts aswell ... and yes it's possible.

Comment: your controller is not of interest in this case though it could be heavily optimized i.e. with the @ParamConverter annotation. Please provide your entity classes and formtypes :D

Comment: added entities, dont have code repository folder at the moment
and i'll take a look for now at ParamConverter