# Fill FormType based on Entity input Symfony2

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I have a Entitiy of TeamMembers, that has a list of Specifications that can have for each specification a value.

But how can I get a full list of the Specifications, with a field behind each specification where I can fill in a SpecificationValue.

That value will be stored in the SpecificationValue Entitiy with a ForeignKey to TeamMember and Specification.

So I want a list: [TeamMember edit_form > Specifications[] > SpecificationValue]

More info:

```
// FORM
class SpecificationValueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value')
            ->add('specification')
            ->add('teammember')
        ;
    }

// ENTITY
class SpecificationValue
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Specifications")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="specification_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $specification; // refernce for specification entity > name, type[ENUM('input','textarea')]

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teammember")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teammember_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $teammember;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $value;  // value that can be filled in for each 


// ENTITY
class TeamMember
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=250)
     */
    protected $name; // and some other fields, now skipped for the example

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SpecificationValue", mappedBy="specifications")
     */
    protected $specifications;
```

///

```
 /**
     * Add specificationValue
     *
     * @param \Foobar\MyBundle\Entity\SpecificationValue $specifications
     * @return SpecificationValue
     */
    public function addSpecification(\Foobar\MyBundle\Entity\SpecificationValue $specifications)
    {
        $this->specifications[] = $specifications;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove specifications
     *
     * @param \Foobar\MyBundle\Entity\SpecificationValue $specifications
     */
    public function removeSpecification(\Foobar\MyBundle\Entity\SpecificationValue $specifications)
    {
        $this->specifications->removeElement($specifications);
    }

    /**
     * Get specifications
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSpecifications()
    {
        return $this->specifications;
    }

     /**
     * Get specifications
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSpecification()
    {
        return $this->specification;
    }
```

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763192/symfony2-filling-all-fields-of-table-related-to-a-entity ...

Comment: phrase a correct question please... What list ? a form-type or what? selectboxes? ... supply all the needed entities and form-types if you'd like to receive an answer. nobody is going to code this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Entity field-type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) in a form to be able to select from your collection of Specification entities.

- Add to your TeamMember form-type a [collection field-type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html) ( with allow_add, prototype option )  of SpecificationValue form-types

**TeamMemberType**

```
->add('specifications', 'collection', array( 
    'type' => new SpecificationValueType(),
    'allow_add' => true, 
     // ... other options
  ))
```

- Add to your specificationValue form-type an '**entity**' field for the specification and a 'value' field ( *text?* ) for the according value.

**SpecificationValueType**

```
->add('specification', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'YourBundle:SpecificationValue',
      'property' => 'name',
      // ... other options
  ))
->add('value')
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds easier then it looks like for me.

    $builder->add('specifications', 'collection', 
                array(  'type' => new \Foobar\MyBundle\Form\SpecificationValueType(), 
                        'allow_add' => true, 
                        'by_reference' => false
                    )
            );

But what about the rest.

Comment: what's in your specificationValueType ? add it to the question.

Comment: _Neither property "specification" nor method "getSpecification()" nor method "isSpecification()" exists in class "FooBar\MyBundle\Entity\TeamMemberType"_ 
> I have the _construct with the specifications as ArrayCollection, and the addSpecification, removeSpecification, getSpecifications in the TeamMemberType Entity.

Comment: .. specificationValueType does not need teammember... you want to edit your teammember or a list of specificationvalues for different members?! question says TeamMember edit_form

Comment: Typo. I added both indeed to TeamMember Entity. See startpost.

Comment: then there should be a collection of specification form types in your teammember form aswell

Comment: I want to add/edit a team member, and show a list over there (Specifications Entity), and store the specs in the SpecificationsValue table. With a FK for teammember and specification.

Comment: sorry dude i cant write all the code for you ... i think the hint to collection and entity field types should be enough to solve this puzzle, right? :)

Comment: next time draw a picture of how your form shall look or something like that :D